# Could not identify the datetime string

Tags: datetime, coldfusion

While going through an API documentation, I found that it returns date-time in the following format.

```
2015-03-17T13:49:31.2735318-04:00
```

Apart from the date part in the beginning, I could not recognize the format. What does the various fragments of the above date-time string represent? I want to parse the string to `ColdFusion` datetime object.

Comment: Is it not the Timezone (GMT) included, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

The part up to the letter T is the date in yyyy-mm-dd format.

The letter T separates the date and time components.

The time is HH:mm:ss followed by fractions of a second to 7 decimal places.

The -04:00 is the offset from UTC.

Comment: 8601, but yes: that's what it is

Comment: Thanks for recognizing it.